# A question regarding Lemma 15.28 of Isaacs' CTFG

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a fixed prime and $B$ be a $p-block$ of $G.$

Lemma 15.28 of Isaacs' Character Theory of Finite Groups says that each $\varphi\in IBr(G)\bigcap B$ can be written as a $\mathbb{Z}$ linear combination of Brauer characters of the form $\hat{\chi}$ for $\chi\in Irr(G)\bigcap B.$

**Question:** Can every $\hat{\chi}$ $\bigg(\text{where }\chi\in Irr(G)\bigcap B\bigg)$ be written as a linear combination of (probably a $\mathbb{C}$ linear combination?) of $\varphi\in IBr(G)\bigcap B$?

Thank you!!

Comment: You seem to be just asking about the decomposition numbers, which are non-negative integers. So $\hat\chi$ is a non-negative linear combination of irreducible Brauer characters, and the coefficients are the decomposition numbers.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Every $\hat{\chi}$ is a linear combination of $\{\varphi|\varphi\in IBr(G)\}$ and the coefficients are decomposition numbers. But is every $\hat{\chi}$ is a linear combination of $\{\varphi|\varphi\in IBr(G)\bigcap B\}$?

Comment: Yes, if $\chi$ and $\phi$ belong to different blocks then $d_{\chi,\phi}=0$.